# Is there a way to draw a line programmatically on tradingview?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pine-script

I need to draw a multiple horisontal lines to mark different price levels.
For now i've only come up with this pine script:

```
//@version=4
study(title = "H1",overlay=true)
plot(close)
lev1=0.00039623
hline(lev1,linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.purple, linewidth=3)
lev2=0.00038907
hline(lev2,linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.purple, linewidth=3)
lev3=0.00036019
hline(lev3,linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.purple, linewidth=3)
lev4=0.00040168
hline(lev4,linestyle=hline.style_solid, color=color.purple, linewidth=3)
```

But this script creates indicator and i can't drag the lines.
Is there any way to draw a lines like you do with drawing panel tools, but programmatically? May be via javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Lines drawn by a script cannot be manipulated by the user on the chart.